# What's the best Dutch language pack for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, language-package

I currently working with a Magento 2.0 installation with sample data (LUMA template). Is there any dutch language pack available for all the strings?

https://github.com/Adwise/magento2-nl_NL-language\

This is the only language pack I've found but only 50% of the strings are translated.

It's also not a problem for me to pay for a language pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Crowdin project](https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2) for the Dutch translations, which is at 89%. It also seems that Mageplaza published [a module](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-dutch-language-pack.html), based on the Crowdin project.

Please share your experiences with the Dutch language packs :)